# Иконка вышла за пределы блока и пропала

Tags: html, css

В шапке есть иконка (картинкой).
После добавление flexbox в шапку проекта она исчезла, я так понял вышла за пределы блока. Но раньше она отображалась за его пределами.

```css
.b-wrap-all { min-height: 100%; overflow:hidden; min-width:1250px; max-width:1450px; margin:0 auto; background:#fff; }

.b-header { height:230px; position:relative;  background:asset-url("x11.png", images) repeat-x; z-index:101;  }

.flex { display: flex; flex-direction: row; justify-content: space-around; align-items: center; }


.b-top-basket { right:24px; top:24px; color:#fff; font-size:12px; line-height:14px; }
.b-top-basket a { color:#fff; font-size:13px; text-decoration:none; }
.b-top-basket a:hover { text-decoration:underline; }
.b-top-basket a:first-child { font-size:11px; }
.b-top-basket:before { content:''; width:23px; height:18px; background:asset-url("i-bask.png", images) no-repeat; left:-36px; top:16px; position:absolute; }
.b-top-basket-full:after { content:''; width:16px; height:15px; background:asset-url("i-bask-full.png", images) no-repeat; left:-30px; top:2px; position:absolute; }
```

```html
<div class="b-wrap-all">
  <div class="b-header">
    <div class="flex">
      <div class="logo"></div>
      <div class="address"></div>
      <div class="form"></div>
      <div class="basket">
        <div class="b-top-basket"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Добавляю `overflow:visible;` не помогает. Убираю `left:-36px; top:16px;` и она появляется в левом верхнем углу блока.

Что можно сделать чтобы иконка отображалась?

UPD: Иконка (::before) переместилась в левый край экрана. получается она правильно съехала вниз и влево, но только не от блока `b-top-basket`, а от всего `b-header`

Comment: добавьте html так же не понятно

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У Вас у иконки абсолютное позиционирование, но у родителя ни у `.b-top-basket`, ни у `.basket` не задан `position: relative`, поэтому иконка позиционируется относительно окна браузера. + у обертки четкие границы с `overflow: hidden`.

Решение - задать `.b-top-basket` или `.basket` `position: relative`:

```css
.b-wrap-all { min-height: 100%; overflow:hidden; min-width:1250px; max-width:1450px; margin:0 auto; background:#fff; }

.b-header { height:230px; position:relative;  background:asset-url("x11.png", images) repeat-x; z-index:101;  }

.flex { display: flex; flex-direction: row; justify-content: space-around; align-items: center; }


.b-top-basket { right:24px; top:24px; color:#fff; font-size:12px; line-height:14px; }
.b-top-basket a { color:#fff; font-size:13px; text-decoration:none; }
.b-top-basket a:hover { text-decoration:underline; }
.b-top-basket a:first-child { font-size:11px; }
.b-top-basket:before { content:''; width:23px; height:18px; background:asset-url("i-bask.png", images) no-repeat; left:-36px; top:16px; position:absolute; }
.b-top-basket-full:after { content:''; width:16px; height:15px; background:asset-url("i-bask-full.png", images) no-repeat; left:-30px; top:2px; position:absolute; }

/* мои стили только для наглядности примера  */
.logo,
.adress,
.form,
.basket {
height: 100px;
width: 20%;
background: #ddd;
}

/* Решение:  */
.basket {
position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="b-wrap-all">
  <div class="b-header">
    <div class="flex">
      <div class="logo"></div>
      <div class="address"></div>
      <div class="form"></div>
      <div class="basket">
        <div class="b-top-basket"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

[Поведение position: absolute | relative | ...](http://htmlbook.ru/css/position)